# is ios app needed to develop tvos app

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I am planing to start developing tvos app. As apple tv has app store I can develop application which is only for apple tv right ? No need to create application for ios devices. I am confuse as I am searching through and get datas like people are adding extensions to their ios app to develop tvos app . So if so that tvos apps are extensions of ios apps then I must create ios app to develop TVos app or it can be possible that i can create app which is for only tvos nothing related to ios app. Please explain me approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it makes sense you can have a tv only app. People create companion apps in a number of cases, perhaps because the iOS app makes sense on its own, but also because text entry and things like authentication aren't so easy on the tv.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to extend an iOS app to create a tvOS app (IMHO). Nevertheless, you can use most of the iOS frameworks for your tvOS app. If you are planning to write an app which shows some content, you might start with a TVML app.
Good introduction points are:
[Apples Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/) or [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114886/beginning-tvos-development-with-tvml-tutorial)